# How do I show org links pointing to an entry?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, org-link

I have `org-capture` templates setup (but the default `Todo` template works the same way) to create a link in the resultant file to the text that was selected when `org-capture` was invoked.  This allows me to go to my `TODO` item - that was created by `org-capture` - where the originally selected text is now a link to the position in the file from where `org-capture` was called.

My question is, how can I see - from the original file, line or header in org mode - all the links that are pointing to that particular place?

My use cases are, for instance:

- I would like to navigate to notes I've made for a particular group of clock entries
- I would like to see all the linked `TODO`'s for a particular line of code

Answer (score 1):

If you only use org id style links it could be as simple as:

```
(org-search-view nil (concat "{\\[\\[id:" (org-id-get) "\\]}"))
```

Of course this does not cover all your listed use cases but would give you a list of headings that have links to the current heading.

I do something like this to give me an agenda list of all the entries that link to the email thread I am reading in mu4e.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that within org-mode that I can see.

If you can modify the target file, you can add "backward" links: that's probably ugly and will not work in general, since you probably don't want to add to your code file N backlinks to the N TODO items that link to that piece of code.

If you have a single org file (or a small set of org files) that contains the links, you can search for the text (or the filename/line number combination) that they link to: they are text files after all. You can do this without any coding, so this is
probably the easiest way if the requirements are met.

Another way is to create an indexing file: it would basically store the target (selected text, pathname, line number) would be used as the key for an entry and the set of backlinks to all the places that link to it would be used as the value for that index entry. The org-capture template would search this file for the target and add a backlink if the target is found; otherwise create a new entry. You could then write a function that could be invoked on some selected text in a file somewhere: the function could do a fuzzy search for this target in the indexing file and return the set of backlinks.

None of this is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I love [@JonahT](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/68546/38911)'s answer. But the search time was too long on my system.

You could try using [org-super-links](https://github.com/toshism/org-super-links) which creates a backlink's drawer giving you easy access to the files that link to the heading you are working in.